# Implementing numpy einstein summation for sum of dot products

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum, numpy-ufunc

I need to optimize an algorithm, which needs to be fast as possible, for now, its a basic sum over the dot products of 2 vectors problem, but I think my solution is a bit redundant, and Einstein notation can get much faster results. First, I had a single value case:

```
for t in range(2):
  for i2 in range(40):
     for j2 in range(40):
       U_out[i2,j2,t] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
```

I needed to use 8 times in a row, so i came up with another barbaric solution:

```
for t in range(2):
  for i2 in range(40):
    for j2 in range(40):
      U_out[i2,j2,t,0] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,0],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
      U_out[i2,j2,t,1] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,1],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
      U_out[i2,j2,t,2] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,2],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
      U_out[i2,j2,t,3] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,3],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
      U_out[i2,j2,t,4] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,4],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
      U_out[i2,j2,t,5] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,5],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
      U_out[i2,j2,t,6] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,6],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
      U_out[i2,j2,t,7] += np.sum(np.multiply(U_in[:,:,t,7],constants[:,:,j2,i2,t]))
```

Now, the first code, repeated 8 times is around a second, whereas the second code is taking 0.4 seconds. However, i will be using them in an optimization AI algorithm so it will be looping over for weeks, in this form. Variable shapes are:

```
U_out = (40,40,2) 1st code , (40,40,2,8) 2nd code 
U_in  = (40,40,2) 1st code , (40,40,2,8) 2nd code 
constants = (40,40,40,40,2) for both codes
```

Any help, even no Einstein notation but reducing the 2nd code summation to 4 lines like the above would help me a lot.

Comment: If you can show the dimensions of the arrays, in and out, with unique values or symbols, the einsum might write itself.

Comment: What do you mean 'might write itself'

Comment: Looks like `U_in` has shape (M,N,T,Q); `constants` (M,N,K,L,T) and `U_out` (K,L,T,Q), and you are doing the `dot` sums on M,N.  If that's right, the einsum index expression would be 'mntq, mnklt -> kltq'.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works very fast!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).